# ng-options order groups by group name

Tags: angularjs

I have a select that uses ng-options directive in my code:

```
ng-options="cls as cls.name group by cls.related for cls in classes track by cls.name | orderBy:'related' "
```

The cls.related might have value:

1. 'related'
2. 'not related'

The problem is that ng-options puts the not related group on top and related group under it. How can I change the order?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
ng-options="cls as cls.name group by cls.related for cls in classes track by cls.name | orderBy:'related':true "
//Doc:
{{ orderBy_expression | orderBy : expression : reverse}}
```

Comment: unfortunately it orders the elements inside the groups and has no effect on group themselves